# Switching between accounts then looping through email

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I am attempting to dump all emails in the junk email folder of a NON-Default outlook account into the inbox so that I can then perform additional logic on the email.
However I am unable to figure out how to reference the junk box or even the inbox of the non-default account, my code keeps going through my default account even with an account check in place.

```
Public Sub New_Mail()
Dim oAccount As Outlook.Account
Dim objSourceFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objDestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
dim lngCount as long

lngcount = 0

For Each oAccount In Application.Session.Accounts  ' cycle through accounts till we find the one we want
    If oAccount = "desired.account@domain.ca" Then

        Set objSourceFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderJunk)   ' select junk folder of the account
        Set objDestFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)    ' select inbox of the account

        For lngCount = objSourceFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1 ' Go through all items in inbox, if a mail object, move into inbox
            Set objVariant = objSourceFolder.Items.Item(dblCount)
            DoEvents
                If objVariant.Class = olMail Then

                    Set objCurrentEmail = objVariant                ' the inbox item is an email, so change object type to olMail (email object)

                    objCurrentEmail.Categories = "red category"

                    objCurrentEmail.Move objDestFolder             ' Move the email to the required folder

                End If
        Next
   End If
Next
End Sub
```

---

EDIT:
After Eric's Answer I'd like share my now working code.

```
Private Sub clearJunk()

    Dim objVariant As Variant                   ' Variant object to handle and inbox item
    Dim objCurrentEmail As Outlook.MailItem     ' Temporary email object for logic
    Dim dblCount As Double                      ' Double used to count email items in the inbox
    Dim objStore As Outlook.Store               ' Store Object to cycle through email accounts
    Dim objRoot As Outlook.Folder               ' Folder object to define Inbox of desired account
    Dim folders As Outlook.folders              ' FolderS object to holder folders...lol 
    Dim Folder As Outlook.Folder                ' Temporary Folder object
    Dim foldercount As Integer                  ' integer to count folders in account
    Dim objInboxFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder    ' MAPI folder object to move emails to or from
    Dim objJunkFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder     ' MAPI folder object to move emails to or from
    Dim objRandomFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder   ' MAPI folder object to move emails to or from

    '--------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Cycle through each account in outlook client and find desired account
    For Each objStore In Application.Session.Stores         
        If objStore = "desired.account@domain.ca" Then      ' If we find the account

            Set objRoot = objStore.GetRootFolder        ' Store int objRoot Object

            On Error Resume Next

                Set folders = objRoot.folders           ' Check if it has folders
                foldercount = folders.Count

                If foldercount Then                         ' if folders exist

                    For Each Folder In folders              ' Go through each folder AND ....

                        ' Look for Junk Email folder, Inbox Folder, and some random customer folder.
                        ' Store in individual objects for future referencing
                        If Folder.FolderPath = "\\desired.account@domain.ca\Junk Email" Then
                            Set objJunkFolder = Folder
                        End If
                        If Folder.FolderPath = "\\desired.account@domain.ca\Inbox" Then
                           Set objInboxFolder = Folder
                        End If
                        If Folder.FolderPath = "\\desired.account@domain.ca\Random Custom Folder" Then
                            Set objRandomFolder = Folder
                        End If

                    Next

                End If

            ' Now we have everything identified lets move emails!

            For dblCount = objJunkFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
                Set objVariant = objJunkFolder.Items.Item(dblCount)
                DoEvents
                If objVariant.Class = olMail Then

                    Set objCurrentEmail = objVariant                

                    objCurrentEmail.Categories = "Red Category"
                    objCurrentEmail.Move objInboxFolder

                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call Store.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) for the non-default accounts.  Get the Store object from the Account.DeliveryStore property - in most cases that will be the correct store unless for example it is a PST account that has messages delivered to another account's store (perhaps even the default account's store).

Comment: Awesome!
That lead me into the right direction for sure! 
I'll edit my original post to show everyone how I got it to work, and I've ran this several times with 100% success.
Thank you so much Eric!